# How many natural numbers less than 1,000,000,000 are multiples of 5 or 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I used the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle and I got $200,000,000$ (multiples of $5$ less than $10^9$, obtained by $10^9 / 5$) + $124,857,142$ ( multiples of $7$ less than $10^9$, obtained by $10^9 / 7$ and round it down) - $28,571,428$ ( multiples of both $5$ and $7$ that are less than $10^9$, obtained by $10^9 / 35$ because only multiples of $35$ is multiple of both $5$ and $7$ ) since the rule says $|A ∪ B| = |A| + |B| - |A ∩ B|$.

So my equation is: $200,000,000 + 124,857,142 - 28,571,428 = 314,285,714 $, which is a rather big number so I think I might have done something wrong. Is my reasoning correct? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: It is 142857142 not 124857142. Otherwise your reasoning is correct, and this big number is normal.

Comment: I see, thank you guys very much for helping out!

Answer (score 5):

Besides your transposed digit, everything you did is completely correct. The correct answer is indeed 314,285,714.
If you'd like to verify that your numbers are correct, I've wrote a little bit of pseudocode that should accurately show that the number you found is absolutely correct.

`counter = 0`
`i = 0;`
`while i < 1000000000{`
  `if i % 5 == 0 or i % 7 == 0 {`
     `counter = counter + 1;`
  `}`
`i = i + 1;`
`}`